# iPhone images on the simulator and the actual device - different bitsPerPixel values?

Tags: iphone, image, ios-simulator

I have code running in an iPhone application I am developing.
Basically, the code needs to load an images and calls:

```
size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
```

I noticed that on the iPhone simulator this call returns 24 and the device itself it returns 32.

Is this behavior by design?
Is it something I can control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes down to the image format.

When using PNGs in an iPhone app, part of the build process when building for device puts PNG images through the pngcrush utility, which optimises the images for use with the iPhone's graphics processor. It has something to do with the fact that the iPhone's graphic processor doesn't natively handle alpha, so it relys on pre-multiplied alpha values.

This could be the difference you are seeing. And the reason you don't see it in the simulator is that the simulator uses the Mac's grahics processor, and therefore can natively handle alpha in PNGs, which means the PNGs aren't 'crushed' during the build process.

I think...

Comment: (I know I wasn't the one who asked the question, but...) Then how to other apps that are on the App Store use images that MUST use transparency? Are they in the .gif format, or something?

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 - the iPhone can handle transparent PNGs, no need to use GIFs. Its simply a different way of handling the transparency. Premultiplying the alpha values during the build phase is an optimisation that saves the iPhone having to do it at runtime. The iPhone's GPU doesn't natively handle a PNG's alpha channel - that isn't to say that it doesn't support transparency - only that it is slower when done on-the-fly. Non-optimised PNGs can be used with transparency, but they are slower to render than optimised PNGs.

Comment: @Jansarien so... how do I optimize PNGs?

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 - it's done automatically when you hit build in Xcode. One of the automatic build phases is to pass each PNG referenced in your Xcode project through the pngcrush utility. You don't have to do anything yourself. This only works for images that are included in your Xcode project, though, images downloaded from external sources at runtime will be unoptimised.