# iPhone Difference Handling Images Between Device and Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, ios-simulator, cgcontext

I have an image with a transparent border, and I am trying to directly manipulate the image pixels, following the Apple guide found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html). Everything works perfectly well when run on the device. However, when I run my code on the simulator, I find that the transparent border of the image slowly turns black with each call to this function. The strange thing is that even if I don't modify the image data, the transparent border still begins to turn black with each call to this function. For example, I see the same problem even if my image manipulation code calls `CGBitmapContextGetData` but doesn't use the returned data pointer. To make the problem go away on the simulator, I have to comment out the call to `CGBitmapContextGetData` (and the freeing of the data pointer of course). Example code that still modifies the image on the simulator:

```
+ (UIImage *) updateImage:(UIImage *)inputImage
{
    UIImage *updatedImage;

    /* Update colors in image appropriately */
    CGImageRef image = [inputImage CGImage];

    CGContextRef cgctx = [ColorHandler CreateARGBBitmapContext:image];
    if (cgctx == NULL)
    {
        // error creating context
        NSLog(@"Error creating context.\n");
        return nil;
    }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};

    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, image);

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    void *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(cgctx);

    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgctx);
    updatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data)
    {
        free(data);
    }

    return updatedImage;    
}
```

I read [the comments and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469659/iphone-images-on-the-simulator-and-the-actual-device-different-bitsperpixel-va) regarding how images are managed differently between the device and simulator, but it hasn't helped me figure out my problem.

The only difference between my `CreateARGBBitmapContext` and the example one is that I call `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` instead of `CGColorSpaceCreateWithName` because I am targeting iOS. The image is edited exactly as designed when run on the iOS device.

I am currently doing all image manipulation in the main thread for debugging this issue.

Specs: Mountain Lion, XCode 4.5.2, iOS 6 device, iOS 6 simulator

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by allowing Quartz to allocate and manage the memory for the bitmap [(Apple doc)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate). To do this, I updated the call to `CGBitmapContextCreate` in `CreateARGBBitmapContext` to pass NULL, and I removed all references to `bitmapData`.

```
// Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits 
// per component. Regardless of what the source image format is 
// (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
// specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,
                                pixelsWide,
                                pixelsHigh,
                                8,      // bits per component
                                bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                colorSpace,
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

Then, in the `updateImage` method, I removed the freeing of `data`. Now it seems to work on both device and simulator without any issues.

Comment: Perhaps you weren't zeroing the memory passed to CGBitmapContextCreate()?

Comment: @tc. I wasn't zeroing the memory passed to CGBitmapContextCreate. The Apple example also was not zeroing the memory. I haven't gotten a chance to test if that also fixes the problem, but what makes you think it would? I assume that CGContextDrawImage overwrites all of the data anyway.

Comment: If your image has transparency, then `CGContextDrawImage` will do an alpha blend by default; you can do a direct copy with `kCGBlendModeCopy` (and perhaps this is what you want for efficiency). I'd also suggest using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` if you do not need to support below iOS 4.

Comment: @tc. I see your point. I'll give your advice a try and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @tc. I added a call to `CGContextSetBlendMode`, setting `kCGBlendModeCopy` as you suggested. However, I don't understand how I can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` if I want to access the pixel data? Don't I have to use a bitmap context to access the pixel data directly? I haven't examined the data returned by `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, but I don't think that editing that data will in fact edit the image. Thank you for the `kCGBlendModeCopy` suggestion in any case.